# Volume mounts when setting up Wordpress with docker

Tags: customization, docker

[Quickstart: Compose and WordPress](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) proposes the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

For persisting database data, a volume is created:

> - The docker volume `db_data` persists any updates made by Wordpress to the database.

but nothing is mentioned about the wordpress container...

**Questions:**

1. should I follow the same approach and create volumes for the `wordpress` container, in order to persist the data that are going to be added (by posts, uploads, themes)?
2. If yes, which paths / directories should I point to?

---

## Update :

Same question on stackoverflow has drawn more attention: [Volume mount when setting up Wordpress with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202531/volume-mount-when-setting-up-wordpress-with-docker)

Comment: This isn't a docker stack exchange, and somewhat misleadingly, the official WP docker image was not created by WP and is the docker teams creation. However I assume the `wordpress` container is going to be pulled from dockerhub somehow. Try Serverfault but check if it's in scope there first, this stack is for developing with WordPress not devops

Comment: The third bullet of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions *"server configuration for WordPress"* and I thought my question could be considered on-topic for this category. Anyway... thanks Tom.

Comment: Sure how to setup basic Nginx rules for a multisite might be on topic, but your question demands docker knowledge and docker knowledge only. There is no WP best practice here other than what your needs are. For information about the WordPress container, you're going to have to look for the people who wrote it and the documentation. There is no official WP docker container, https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/ was created by Docker, not the WordPress community

Comment: Thanks again, I had no idea about the "official" docker image not being actually official :-)

Comment: it's "official docker" not "official WP", it's quite misleading :(